Irreducible $2$-dimensional representation of $D_n$
Show that for $n\geq3$ the dihedral group $D_n$ has an irreducible representation of dimension $2$. Is it unique?
I thought of doing it this way: let's count the conjugacy classes of $D_n$, which are, if I'm not mistaken, $(n+3)/2$, and use that $|D_n| = \sum_{i=1}^{(n+3)/2} (\dim V_i)^2$ where $V_i$ are the irreducible representations. Thus, we get $2n = d_1^2 + \ldots + d_{(n+3)/2}^2$, and I want to show that at least one of the $d_i$ is equal to $2$, but I don't know how to do it...

The dihedral group is defined by a 2D rep which involves symmetries of a polygon. You can show this is an irrep. There's ambiguity in which rotations and reflections the generators correspond to, related to the automorphisms of the group. You can pursue this route without knowing the squared dimensions add up to $|G|$.

What is this representation of the symmetries of a polygon? I do not know it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group

$D_n$ is the symmetries of a regular $n$-gon. If your $n$-gon is centred on the origin, each of these symmetries is a linear operator, and therefore defines a representation. Can you go from there?

Ok, but is it unique?

There are posts on general analysis of irreps of $D_{n}$; for example, see this post; of course, it might be a different story if we are working in a field of positive characteristic...

As $n\geq 3$, $D_n$ is not abelian, and therefore there exists a nonlinear irreducible character $\chi\in\text{Irr}(D_n)$. Consider a rotation $r\in D_n$. Then $|D_n:\langle r\rangle|=2$. Write the restricted character $\chi_{\langle r\rangle}=\sum_{i=1}^tn_i\lambda_i$, where the $\lambda_i$ are distinct and linear irreducible characters of $\langle r\rangle$ (as $\langle r\rangle$ is abelian) and the $n_i$ are nonnegative integers. Then,
$$\chi(1)=\sum_{i=1}^tn_i\leq\sum_{i=1}^tn_i^2=\sum_{i=1}^t\sum_{j=1}^tn_in_j[\lambda_i,\lambda_j]=[\chi_{\langle r\rangle},\chi_{\langle r\rangle}]\leq|D_n:\langle r\rangle|[\chi,\chi]=2.$$
Hence $\chi(1)=2$.
Now, the uniqueness of character $\chi$ depends on $n$. If $n=3$, the equality
$$\sum_{\varphi\in\text{Irr}(D_3)}\varphi(1)^2=|D_3|=6$$ forces the uniqueness. On the other hand, if $n=5$ then $|(D_5)'|=5$ and therefore number of linear irreducible characters of $D_5$ is $|D_5/(D_5)'|=2$. Using again the previous equality and the bound of the degrees of the irreducible characters we deduce that $D_5$ has $2$ nonlinear characters with degree $2$.
